# Connect to prisma from mulitple servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, prisma

I have a server where my database is hosted at, and I have multiple other servers trying to access that same database.

the quest is: do I have to include the `schema.prisma` file in the code base of every server, and if so don't you think that this will make it a bit hard to edit the schema, since if you do it in one server, then you have to also do it in all other servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use prisma in all servers, then yes you would have to keep a copy of `schema.prisma` in all the servers.

I'm not sure if this is necessarily difficult, atleast not more so than any other solution. You should see the `schema.prisma` file as a part of your code/application, which is responsible for representing the database tables in your application layer.

Even if you didn't use Prisma and used some other solution to access your Database, that solution would also need code that has to be updated and consistent with your current state of the database. For example, if you were using Sequelize, the database tables is represented using model files and so those would have to be updated across all your servers.